# Can OTP (One-Time password) be used to protect data after intrusion has been detected?

Tags: one-time-password, sms, social-engineering

I am working on Social Engineering attacks happening via SMSs. Let's assume a person receives an SMS asking him to click on a malicious link. If a virus is installed on the person's device, how can OTP be used to prevent this attack? If OTP cannot be used, are there other techniques that can be used to mitigate this type of attack?

Comment: What does the password control access to? Where/what is this data that you mention in the title and how does that relate to the scenario in the body of your post? Your scenario is quite confusing and appears to be missing some details.